# CTMC: If the transition probability is >0 at one moment, then it is also >0 from that moment onwards

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume that $\{X_t:t\geq0\}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain with values on a discrete (countable, but possibly not finite) set $S$.

Notation: for $i,j\in S$ and $t\geq0$,

$p_{ij}(t):=\mathrm{P}\{X_t=j|X_0=i\}$.

---

I want to prove that, for fixed $i$ and $j$ in $S$, the existence of a $s>0$ so that

$p_{ij}(s)>0$

implies

$\forall t>s, p_{ij}(t)>0$.

---

I've tried lots of things (within my limited knowledge on the subject) and researched as far as I could, but I can't figure it out and I'm extremely frustrated because it seems really easy.

I'll greatly appreciate detailed answers, since I'm afraid of not understanding the intermediate steps.

---

---

EDIT: As I predicted, it's actually quite simple, but I still want to understand all the details (see comments below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see this is that in a continuous-time Markov chain, you always have a positive probability of staying put in a state for any amount of time.

(The time it takes to leave a state has the $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ distribution, where $\lambda$ is the sum of all transition rates out of that state, and the exponential distribution is unbounded.)

If we make up the notation $p_i^*(t)$ to denote the probability of staying put in state $i$ for $t$ units of time, then a lower bound on $p_{ij}(t)$ is $p_{ij}(s) \cdot p_j^*(t-s)$: we definitely end up going from $i$ to $j$ in $t$ seconds if we go from $i$ to $j$ in $s$ seconds and then stay put for $t-s$ seconds more. Both factors are positive, so the result is positive.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation convinces me, but I want to clarify a couple of details...

1. Your definition of $\lambda$ would be $\lambda:=\sum_{j\neq i}q_{ij}$, where $q_{ij}:=\frac{dp_{ij}}{dt}(t)|t=0$, right?

Comment: 2. I'm also looking for a "rigorous" definition of $p_i^*(t)$. Is it equal to $P\{X_t=i|X_0=i\}\equiv p_{ii}(t)$?

Comment: 3. And you can assume that $p_i*(t)>0$ for all $t>0$ because, otherwise, it would be a "degenerate" Markov chain and it wouldn't make sense considering state $i$. Am I understanding it well?

Comment: (And that's it--there won't be a 4th one)

Comment: 1. I'm used to treating $q_{ij}$, not $p_{ij}$, as fundamental, but yes. 2. yes, 3. yes, although you can also put a lower bound $p_{ii}(t) \ge e^{-\lambda t}$.

Comment: 1-2. OK. 3. Now, that I stop and think about it, I finally understand this "famous" inequality, to which I hadn't paid much attention since I first saw it. I believe yours is a better justification than mine. And the fact that the Exp distribution is unbounded also works here.

Comment: So I eventually accept your answer. Thanks again!